# Javascript heap out of memory with angular app building docker image

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx

I am running into the following error at the ng build --prod step of building a docker image of an angular application.

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

This is what my dockerfile looks like.

```
##### Stage 1
FROM node:latest as node
LABEL author="David Andrews"
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . .


RUN npm run build -- --prod

##### Stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
VOLUME /var/cache/nginx
COPY --from=node /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

This error does not occur when I run the build for prod and only occurs when building the docker image. I have tried increasing the memory limit and it worked a few times but then began to fail again.

Comment: So you mean that something like this `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8000` is not working for you as permanent solution or you have tried something else ? Have you checked the server load/ram usage while building in case we are talking about a self hosted CI server?
`

Comment: Having the same issue: angular project that builds properly (my environment is Win10 pro, node 10.14.1, angular 7.2.15) but receiving heap out of memory when run in node:latest container.

Anybody with a solution/workaround?